# Outlook Original Sender to CC Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I have Outlook VBA code that forwards the original email to predetermined people, appends the email subject and adds some text to the email body.

I need to pull the original sender of the email (using senderEMailAddress MailItem I am sure) and place that email address in the cc of the email being forwarded.

```
Sub CADREemailFWD()

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMsg = objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Set objForward = objMsg.Forward

Set myitem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

objForward.Recipients.Add "dlud@blahblah.com"
objForward.Recipients.Add "mcha@blahblah.com"
objOrignialBody = objForward.Body
objOriginalSubject = objForward.Subject

objForward.Subject = "[CADRE REQUEST #  ] " & objOriginalSubject
objForward.Display
objForward.Body = "[CADRE REQUEST #   ]" & BodyofEmail & objOrignialBody

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
objForward.Recipients.Add(myItem.SenderEmailAddress).Type = olCC
```

or

```
objForward.Recipients.Add(myItem.Sender).Type = olCC
```